# Use Ruby database on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a mysql database with Ruby. I want to use it on my Rails app. How can I do it? How can I read data with Rails without any database?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the real question is, but by default Rails uses a SQLite DB for development and testing. This can be changed in the `database.yml` file found in the `config` directory.

However I would really start here [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Comment: Sorry about questions style.I'm the newbie of CS.I will look the guide and sqlite tutorials.Thank's.